# QuillJS merges subsequent p tags into one with Angular 7 + ngx-quill

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I just integrated quilljs into my app.
The one problem that I am facing right now some weird behavior with p tags.

as an example, in my component I am setting up reactive form:

```
this.fullDocumentFormGroup = new FormGroup({
        fullDocument: new FormControl('<p>some</p><p>html</p>', [Validators.required])
      });
```

And in the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="fullDocumentFormGroup" class="full-document">

  <quill-editor placeholder="Detailed documentation of your invention here..."
                [style]="{'min-height': '250px'}"
                bounds="self"
                formControlName="fullDocument"
                [readOnly]="isProjectLocked()">
  </quill-editor>

</form>
```

This code eventually sets the content of the editor as:

```
<p>somehtml</p>
```

I tested it with textarea, to check if the reactive form is stripping it out, and it is not.

Tried adding an attribute to quill-editor `[sanitize]="true"` => nothing changes.

What am I missing?

**ANOTHER THOUGHT**

Possibly, it strips all the tags and simply wraps the content with `p` tags. However, if I add another '
' between the paragraphs, it stays formatted properly.

Comment: Anyone? Any idea?

Comment: This seems to only be an issue with the reactive forms approach, I am working around it using ngModel.

Comment: @Ryan yep, having the same problem with PrimeNG's editor which uses Quill, it works only with ngModel and not formControl in my project but I can't seem to reproduce it in an empty project.

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered this problem, which was mostly apparent when the quill editor is rendered within tabs or steppers. The solution I've used is to use `*ngIf` to display the quill editor only when it is in view (An alternative is to trigger it on `afterViewInit` if what I've done doesn't exactly fit your project)

i.e. in my instance, I am using `mat-tabs` to show different views. 
I'm getting the tab index with:

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabIndex" (selectedIndexChange)="changeIndex($event)">
```

ts:

```
changeIndex(index) {
this.tabIndex = index;
}
```

And then on the component, set it to display only when the tabIndex is '1'

```
<ngx-quill *ngIf="tabIndex==1"> </ngx-quill>
```

Comment: Thank you! This has been bugging me for hours. My quill editor was in a tab and I had no idea why other solution didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with Nebular UI, using **NbTabsetComponent** and **ngx-quill** and i solved with **lazyload** prop in **nb-tab** component.I think this same solution (use lazyload) work to another tabset component.

```
<nb-tabset>
  <nb-tab lazyload>
    <quill-editor
      [modules]="editor_modules"
      [(ngModel)]="content"
    ></quill-editor>
  </nb-tab>
</nb-tabset>
```

Comment: You really saved my day, thank you! I'm also encountered this issue in ngx-admin (which uses Nebular UI) while placing the editor instances inside some tabs.

Comment: Thanks for comment man. I also losed a lot of time with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the newer version of Nebular UI (>7.0), use `lazyLoad` (camel case)

```
<nb-tabset>
  <nb-tab lazyLoad>
    <quill-editor
       ...
    ></quill-editor>
  </nb-tab>
</nb-tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this behavior by using hack with use of `setTimeout`:

In HTML:

```
<quill-editor formControlName="fullDocument"></quill-editor>
```

When you're setting this field in typescript wrap `patchValue` using `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    formGroup.patchValue({fullDocument: fullDocumentHtml});
});
```

I've even tried changing line separator from `<p>` to `<div>` in Quill config, but it didn't help at all :).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I resolved it by just using a timeout before setting the data into the form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).